# XSD Non sense error. The attribute 'filter' is not allowed

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I got the next XML:

```
<!-- language: xml -->
<Message name="Msg1" type="SIMPLE">
    <Doc> message to send </Doc>
    <Parameters>
        <Parameter name="param1" type="byte" filter="2" mask="On">
            <Fields>
                <Field encode="hex">
                    <Values>
                        <Value name="INDICATOR" id="0"/>
                    </Values>
                </Field>
            </Fields>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter name="param2" type="byte" filter="3" mask="On"/>
        <Parameter name="param3" type="byte"/>
    </Parameters>
</Message>
```

and my XSD file is this one:

```
    <xs:element name="Message" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="Doc" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Parameters" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:element name="Parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                        <xs:element ref="Doc" minOccurs="0"/>
                                        <xs:element name="Fields" minOccurs="0">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                    <xs:element name="Field" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                                <xs:element ref="Doc" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                                    <xs:element name="Values" minOccurs="0">
                                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                                        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                                            <xs:element ref="Doc" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                                                <xs:element name="Value" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                                                <xs:complexType>
                                                                                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required">
                                                                                        <xs:annotation>
                                                                                            <xs:documentation>Name of the value</xs:documentation>
                                                                                        </xs:annotation>
                                                                                    </xs:attribute>
                                                                                    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required">
                                                                                        <xs:annotation>
                                                                                            <xs:documentation>The value</xs:documentation>
                                                                                        </xs:annotation>
                                                                                    </xs:attribute>
                                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                                            </xs:element>
                                                                        </xs:choice>
                                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                                </xs:element>
                                                            </xs:choice>
                                                            <xs:attribute name="encode" type="xs:string" default="hex">
                                                                <xs:annotation>
                                                                    <xs:documentation>encoding</xs:documentation>
                                                                </xs:annotation>
                                                            </xs:attribute>
                                                        </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                                </xs:choice>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:unique name="unique_filed_name">
                                                <xs:selector xpath="Field"/>
                                                <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
                                            </xs:unique>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:choice>
                                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:attribute name="filter" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:attribute name="mask" type="xs:string"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:choice>
                    </xs:complexType>
                    <xs:unique name="unique_parameter_name">
                        <xs:selector xpath="Parameter"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
                    </xs:unique>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="name">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Unique</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="type" type="MessageTypes" use="required">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Select a valid type</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

and I got this error without sense because I added filter to my XSD:

> Element 'Parameter', attribute 'filter': The attribute 'filter' is not
>   allowed.

could anyone help me on explain me why I got this error that seems difficult to solve?

Comment: Downvoting because you failed to follow up when the question was (partially) answered. It seems you have a history of asking questions and not acknowledging the answers.

Answer (score 0):

When I paste your "schema" into an xs:schema element and run it, I get

```
Error at xs:element on line 3 column 69 of test.xsd:
  Attribute @minOccurs is not allowed on element <xs:element>
Error at xs:element on line 3 column 69 of test.xsd:
  Attribute @maxOccurs is not allowed on element <xs:element>
```

This suggests your xs:element is not actually a top-level element, so we're not seeing the whole picture.

When I fix that, I get a lot more errors, like these:

```
on line 6 of test.xsd:
  The element {Doc} is referenced, but has not been declared
on line 77 of test.xsd:
  The type {MessageTypes} is referenced, but has not been declared
```

When I fix these errors, the instance is valid against the schema.

I can only conclude that in cutting down your real code to the section you have posted, you have inadvertently removed the part that is wrong.

But I agree the message makes no sense. What XSD processor are you using?